# Discovering Jenkins Node Labels in Step Plugin

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to be able to get the list of all Nodes and their labels in Jenkins from a Step Plugin implementation. I think my only access to the Jenkins model from a `Step` plugin is the `StepContext`:

```
public class MyPlugin extends Step { /* Omitted for Brevity */}
```

From the `StepContext` (a property of `Step`) I can access the workspace, the current computer, and various other values... but I cannot seem to access the list of nodes connected to the Jenkins instance.

If you are able to get a list of nodes in a Jenkins Java Plugin, can you please share? I don't want a Groovy solution, as I'm already aware of how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here:

In order to do this, you can can leverage the following import `import jenkins.model.Jenkins`. This gives access to the Jenkins instance using `Jenkins.getInstance()`. The Jenkins instance then has method `getLabel(String name)`.

Finally, `Jenkins.getInstance().getLabel("MyAwesomeLabel").getNodes()` to get all the nodes associated with the given label.

I hope someone else finds this useful.